# draw multiple images on canvas and save to image

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I'm trying to build a constructur where you can apply multiple images, texxt on canvas an then save all it in one image.

I cannot make it work with multiple images

this is the code I have the basis I took from the http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-loader/:

```
   function loadImages(sources, callback) {

    var images = [];
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;
    // get num of sources
    for(i=0; i< sources.length; i++) {
      numImages++;
    }
    for(i=0; i< sources.length; i++) {
      images[i] = new Image();
      images[i].onload = function() {
        if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
          callback(images);
        }
      };
      images[i].src = sources[i];
    }
  }



var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  //var sources = {
  //  darthVader: '/image/CategorieVerkeersborden/Verboden.jpg',
  //  yoda: '/image/CategorieVerkeersborden/Funborden.jpg'
  //};

var sources = []; // I need to add the values to that array dynamically I

$(document).ready(function(){


    $('.add').click(function(){

        if ( $.inArray($(this).siblings('img').attr('src'), sources) == -1 ){
            sources[sources.length] = $(this).siblings('img').attr('src');

        }

        loadImages(sources, function(images) {

            imageElem = document.getElementById('image');


            for (i = 0; i< sources.length; i++){

                context.drawImage(images[i], 0, 0, 300, 200); // this is the part that doesn't work - it draws the last image in the array I guess

            }
    //context.drawImage(images.darthVader, 0, 0, 300, 200);
    //context.drawImage(images.yoda, 0, 0, 200, 150);

  // the above part works 

    imageElem.src = context.canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

        });
     }); 


  });
```

Could anyone tell why it does't work when I try to draw the images through the loop?

Comment: its drawing in same position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function loadImages(sources, callback) {

    var images = [];
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;
    // get num of sources
    for(i=0; i< sources.length; i++) {
      numImages++;
    }
    for(i=0; i< sources.length; i++) {
      images[i] = new Image();
      images[i].onload = function() {
        if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
          callback(images);
        }
      };
      images[i].src = sources[i];
    }
  }



var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  //var sources = {
  //  darthVader: '/image/CategorieVerkeersborden/Verboden.jpg',
  //  yoda: '/image/CategorieVerkeersborden/Funborden.jpg'
  //};

var sources = []; // I need to add the values to that array dynamically I
 sources.push('http://pngimg.com/uploads/grass/grass_PNG10866.png');
 sources.push('http://pngimg.com/uploads/street_light/street_light_PNG11542.png');
 sources.push('http://pngimg.com/uploads/pokeball/pokeball_PNG34.png');
$(document).ready(function(){




        loadImages(sources, function(images) {

            imageElem = document.getElementById('image');


            for (i = 0; i< sources.length; i++){

                context.drawImage(images[i], 0, 0, 300, 200); // this is the part that doesn't work - it draws the last image in the array I guess

            }
    //context.drawImage(images.darthVader, 0, 0, 300, 200);
    //context.drawImage(images.yoda, 0, 0, 200, 150);

  // the above part works 

    imageElem.src = context.canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

        });



  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

`ctx.drawImage(image, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)`
[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

In canvas you are drawing the image at position (dx,dy) with image width (dWidth) and image height (dHeight). In your case start drawing position is (0,0) with all image width = 300 and height= 200, that's why its overlap all the image, and you are able to see the last Image only.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not the case.... indeed the images are stacked above each other, (this is also how I want it - that will be thansparent png's which should come one on the top of the other, a sort image constructor). But the problem is that now both (for now it is 2) images are the same, last clicked images. So not image 1 and 2 but image 1 and 1 or image 2 and 2.

Comment: also a strange thing. It works only twice. when I click the buutton for the third time it stops drawing. (images won't change)

Comment: its drawingin one position, and you can see background png images also, added a snippet

Comment: Tanks man, You're right. It paints just fine. my problem was also that by repaint it paints in the same order as  it is added to the array of sourses... Stupid, probably make pause from time to time helps ;-)